# R caret Error in sensitivity.default

Tags: r, r-caret

```
> cv.ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 3,
+                         summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
+                         classProbs = TRUE)
> 
> set.seed(35)
> glm.tune.1 <- train(y ~ bool_3,
+                     data = train.batch,
+                     method = "glm",
+                     metric = "ROC",
+                     trControl = cv.ctrl)
Error in sensitivity.default(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"], lev[1]) : 
  input data must have the same two levels
In addition: Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  At least one of the class levels are not valid R variables names; This may cause errors if class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to: X.1, X0, X1
```

Here is an extract of the structure of the data:

```
> str(train.batch)
'data.frame':   128046 obs. of  42 variables:
 $ bool_3              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ bool_brand_cat      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ bool_cat_comp       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 ...
 $ y                   : Factor w/ 3 levels "-1","0","1": 2 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 ...
```

Do I need to set the sensitivity? Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

`y` is a "`Factor w/ 3 levels`". You can't compute sensitivity and specificity unless you have two levels in the outcome (see the note that `input data must have the same two levels`)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this when I received the same message, I  understand why it is being generated based on the explanation, but one can indeed calculate sensitivity for multi class problems

http://www.cs.odu.edu/~mukka/cs495s13/Lecturenotes/Chapter5/recallprecision.pdf

it has not been implemented in caret and it may never will

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to install.packages("caret") again